# A cycle that sends the MacOSX CPU down

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm studying Python and I tried to display more than the 255 classic ASCII code characters. With my surprise, the interpreter goes on displaying the characters and slows down by sending the CPU of my MacOS X 10.14.5 into saturation. Can anyone explain it?

```
for i in range(1, 4000):
   print(i, "->", chr(i), end = " ")
```

Comment: How do you know that it's caused by this code? Are you sure you don't have any other apps running? It's find it hard to believe that this code can "send the CPU of your Mac into saturation".

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on my mac, 10.14.2

Comment: I think it's the IDLE 3.7.3. In fact, if you try to run this script in shell, printing is almost instantaneous, while it is running from IDLE when you use the ASCII code 300 it starts to saturate the CPU